# Routing in CakePHP to vanity urls

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.1

I was wondering if there was an easy and best practices way to make routes in CakePHP (routes.php file) to map userIDs to a vanity url?

I have (terrible way to do this) the following test code in my routes page:

```
$users = array
(
    1 => 'firstname-lastname',
    2 => 'firstname2-lastname2'
);   

//profiles
foreach($users as $k => $v)
{
    // LESSONS (Profiles)
    Router::connect('/:user', array('controller' => 'teachers', 'action' => 'contentProfile', $k),
        array('user' => '(?i:'.$v.')'));
}
```

The above code routes my teachers controller with conProfile as the action from:

```
mydomain.com/teachers/contentProfile/1
to
mydomain.com/firstname-lastname
```

Can I connect to the db from the routing page?  Is that not a good idea in terms of performance? Let me know what's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom route class that will look up passed urls in the database and translate them to the correct user id.  Setting a long cache time should mitigate any performance impact of hitting the DB.

[The book documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes) is a little thin, however, but the basic structure is this:

```
class TeachersRoute extends CakeRoute {

  /**
   * Modify incoming parameters so that controller receives the correct data
   */
  function parse($url) {
    $params = parent::parse($url);

    // Add / modify parameter information

    // The teacher id should be sent as the first value in the $params['pass'] array

    return $params;
    // Or return false if lookup failed
  }

  /**
   * Modify parameters so calls like HtmlHelper::url() output the correct value
   */
  function match($url) {
    // modify parameters

    // add $url['slug'] if only id provided

    return parent::match($url);
  }
```

And then in your routes:

```
Router::connect(
  '/:slug', 
  array(
    'controller' => 'teachers', 
    'action' => 'contentProfile'
  ), 
  array(
    'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
    'routeClass' => 'TeachersRoute',
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted. Yeah the book is a little thin too.

Comment: Mark Story has an older article on custom route classes as well: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp

Comment: Yeah I was reading that one when I saw your answer too. Thx again.

Comment: do you put it in App/Lib/MyRouteClass.php or somewhere else? do I create a route folder in Lib?

Comment: How do I make the Html Links (like HtmlHelper->url make them mydomain.com/first-last/media for say /teachers/contentMedia/X

Comment: The recommendation for 1.3 was `app/libs/routes/my_route_class.php`.  Cake2 puts the core routing classes in `lib/Cake/Routing/Route/`, so you could match that with `app/Routing/Route/MyRouteClass.php`.  You'll probably have to include the route class in routes.php, so any path should work.

Comment: For other actions, you'll have to connect another route.  For example `/:slug/media` to the corresponding controller/action.  
You'll also have to specify the urls in array format to the helper, because if you pass strings they cannot be translated based on your route configuration.

Comment: yeah they do, but the url's aren't being mapped correctly. For instance in the above example, when I enter the address mydomain.com/firstname-lastname, it routes correctly, but the html urls that link to there still show the url as mydomain.com/teachers/contentProfile/1