# Make my Cakephp Links have vanity urls

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.1

I am creating routes for php using a CakeRoute class.

The parse method works fine, but how do I make my urls in the app that are mapped liek:

```
mydomain.com/teachers/contentProfile/1

to

mydomain.com/chris-willis
```

I overwrote the parse() method to make my slugs map correctly on a request, but the links don't convert to mydomain.com/chris-willis, they still look the old way.

Comment: this is stupid but works correctly (my hard coded question at the top that is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127337/routing-in-cakephp-to-vanity-urls/13127705#13127705) I DO NOT want to have to do a query in the db and regenerate the routes every time

Answer (score 0):

> mydomain.com/teachers/contentProfile/1

Pass the slug instead of the id to the link: array('slug' => $teacher['Teacher']['slug']);

> mydomain.com/teachers/contentProfile/

Comment: I have way to many links to change. There should be a better way using the match($url) feature

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you're specifying your URLs with the array syntax; CakePHP cannot translate urls if you provided it a string url.

```
$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'teachers', 'action' => 'contentProfile', $id));
```

instead of

```
$this->Html->url('/teachers/contentProfile/' . $id);
```

---

You may have to alternately provide the slug instead of the ID

```
$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'teachers', 'action' => 'contentProfile', 'slug' => 'teacher-name'));
```

---

Or, update your custom route class' `match()` method to lookup the correct slug when only an id is provided.

```
class CustomRoute {
  match($url) {
    if (empty($url['slug']) && isset($url[0])) {
      // lookup slug
    }
    unset($url[0]);
    return parent::match($url);
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, i'll have to try this when I get home, you're just answering all my questions today. In the match() do I need to add in the slug like $url['slug'] = 'my-slug' somewhere?